# Show that $\mathcal{C}[0,1] \cong \mathcal{C}[2,3]$

Tags: continuity, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Show that $\mathcal{C}[0,1] \cong \mathcal{C}[2,3]$

I am given a hint in my text book to define a linear transformation $T: \mathcal{C}[0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{C}[2,3]$.

I will let $T(f) = f(x + 2)$

I'm fairly sure that $kerT = \{ \mathbb{0} \}$ but I'm not sure how to correctly prove it.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: $f(x+2)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [2,3]$

Comment: Assume $f(x) \neq 0$ and $f(x+2) = 0$, then see what happens.

Comment: Actually, your construction of $T$ is slightly wrong. $T(f)(x)=f(x+2)$ is right.